# Drupal 6 parse incoming POST data

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have an Excel file that I need to send data from to my Drupal MySql database.  To do that, I am using an HTTP POST from within the VBA of my Excel sheet as follows:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        URL = "http://localhost:8082/acquia-drupal/node/2"
        objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        objHTTP.send ("string=testdata")
```

I want to use a Drupal page that will parse out the POST data and write it to a table in the Drupal MySql database.

Here is what I have started with,

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['string']))
{
  $trans = $_POST['string'];
  db_query("INSERT INTO {excel} (ExcelData) VALUES (%d')",
  $trans);
}
```

Is this the right direction to go in?  Also, could someone provide some code snippet guidance on parsing out the POST data correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by using a "Drupal page"? Do you mean you want to post the data to a node which will duplicate the content into your database schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processing incoming $_POST data the way you're outlining is a bit like hand-rolling your own web service. It's not a bad thing, necessarily, and sometimes it's the best way to get things talking to each other.

I'd STRONGLY emphasize that you're responsible for your own security, data scrubbing, and SQL injection protection if you use code like that in the snippet you posted, though.

Also, as noted in Eli's comment, it appears that you might be putting this into a node. That's a relatively dangerous way to do it, since anyone could easily pop that node open and start firehosing $_POST data into your database. Creating a module, using hook_menu() to define a url path for your import code, and putting some access control restrictions on that particular url will make things a bit safer.

Comment: I'm a little tired - but what do you mean by "SQL injection protection"? I thought db_query escapes stuff well enough, as long as you use the parameters (as Mike did)

Comment: Yes -- it's just very important to be scrupulous about that when doing raw inserts from incoming $\_POST data, and it's one of the things that often gets stepped around when whipping up quick utilities.

I didn't mean to imply that the specific query that was posted above was unsafe, I'm just used to encouraging paranoia...

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Although, I attacked this problem differently, this info was very helpful.  I was new to Drupal and custom module development for Drupal at the time.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, it looks as if you're simply writing this code in a page with PHP filter on.

If this is indeed the case, that's not a good idea. At the very least, write a custom module, perhaps with some POST-parsing code in a hook_view (or just a simple custom function), and with a hook_menu to set the page address.

As for POST parsing, it's a PHP key=>value array... I haven't found a Drupal-ish way to use it, and some popular modules certainly use it as-is.